# Creating my own NSNotificationCenter, storing objects?

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I'm trying to create my own NSNotificationCenter just to get better at programming. I am running into an EXC_BAD_ACCESS that I can't quite work out.

My method:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)observer forKey:(NSString *)theKey withSelector:(SEL)block {
    NSString *selector = NSStringFromSelector(block);
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:observer, @"o",selector, "s", nil];
    [[observers objectForKey:theKey] addObject:dict];
}
```

I get the error in the initialization of `NSDictionary *dict`, and I don't understand why. The observer being added is a `UIViewController` which is calling this method in it's `viewDidLoad` which runs in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, if that matters.

I get error EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1

Any help would be appreciated,.

Cheers.

Comment: it couldn't be as easy as a missing `@` before the `"s"` could it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:observer, @"o",selector, "s", nil];
```

Looks like you are missing an @ on "s" to me.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:observer, @"o",selector, @"s", nil];
```

For your convenience.